# $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)>\frac{d^2}{d x^2}g(x) \implies \frac{d^2}{d x^2}\log(f(x))> \frac{d^2}{d x^2}\log(g(x))$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Does the following inequality hold?
>   $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)>\frac{d^2}{d x^2}g(x) \implies \frac{d^2}{d x^2}\log(f(x))> \frac{d^2}{d x^2}\log(g(x))$$

EDIT: as this does not hold i wonder whether it works with $\geq$ ?

To give some insights why I was interested in this question:

The fisher-information is defines as $$ I(\theta)=\int \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta ^2}log(f_\theta(x))dP_\theta(x)$$ and I was trying to figure out whether this cannot only be interpreted as the "expected curvature" of the log-likelihood but also as containing information about the expected curvature of the likelihood, but the relationship is at least not as simple as I hoped it would be.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using partial derivatives? The way you wrote $f$ and $g$ indicate it's a function of one variable.

Comment: No, i changed it. Also sorry for the many edits i am writing from my smartphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider $f(x)=e^{-x}$ and $g(x) = c$, where $c>0$ is a real number.

Comment: Or $g(x)=1+\frac12 e^{-x}$ for more drastic effect.

Comment: Thank you! Does it Work with $>=$?

Comment: @VasilyMitch Thanks! This addresses the edited question.

Comment: @0rangetree See the comment of Vasily Mitch